# How do I apply a filter to a register address.

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am having a hard time arranging cells accurately due to the difference between text filtering vs number filtering. I have tried adding numeric columns using formulas "=MID(A140, FIND(":",A140, 1)+1, 5)", but this stacks up my data by register rather than the text. How can I accomplish what I have pasted below?

Here's my table:

```
Register Entry1             Entry2

F28:0    ###_XXX_###-XXXX   XXXXX 
F28:1    ###_XXX_###-XXXX   XXXXX
F28:10   ###_XXX_###-XXXX   XXXXX 
F28:11   ###_XXX_###-XXXX   XXXXX
F28:12   ###_XXX_###-XXXX   XXXXX
F28:2    ###_XXX_###-XXXX   XXXXX
F28:3    ###_XXX_###-XXXX   XXXXX
F28:4    ###_XXX_###-XXXX   XXXXX
F28:5    ###_XXX_###-XXXX   XXXXX
F28:6    ###_XXX_###-XXXX   XXXXX
F28:7    ###_XXX_###-XXXX   XXXXX
F28:8    ###_XXX_###-XXXX   XXXXX
F28:9    ###_XXX_###-XXXX   XXXXX
F29:0    ###_XXX_###-XXXX   XXXXX 
F29:1    ###_XXX_###-XXXX   XXXXX
F29:10   ###_XXX_###-XXXX   XXXXX
F29:2    ###_XXX_###-XXXX   XXXXX
F29:3    ###_XXX_###-XXXX   XXXXX
F29:4    ###_XXX_###-XXXX   XXXXX
F29:5    ###_XXX_###-XXXX   XXXXX
F29:6    ###_XXX_###-XXXX   XXXXX
F29:7    ###_XXX_###-XXXX   XXXXX
F29:8    ###_XXX_###-XXXX   XXXXX
F29:9    ###_XXX_###-XXXX   XXXXX
```

I am trying to achieve this:

```
Register Entry1             Entry2

F28:0    ###_XXX_###-XXXX   XXXXX
F28:1    ###_XXX_###-XXXX   XXXXX
F28:2    ###_XXX_###-XXXX   XXXXX
F28:3    ###_XXX_###-XXXX   XXXXX
F28:4    ###_XXX_###-XXXX   XXXXX
F28:5    ###_XXX_###-XXXX   XXXXX
F28:6    ###_XXX_###-XXXX   XXXXX
F28:7    ###_XXX_###-XXXX   XXXXX
F28:8    ###_XXX_###-XXXX   XXXXX
F28:9    ###_XXX_###-XXXX   XXXXX
F28:10   ###_XXX_###-XXXX   XXXXX
F28:11   ###_XXX_###-XXXX   XXXXX
F28:12   ###_XXX_###-XXXX   XXXXX
F29:0    ###_XXX_###-XXXX   XXXXX 
F29:1    ###_XXX_###-XXXX   XXXXX
F29:2    ###_XXX_###-XXXX   XXXXX
F29:3    ###_XXX_###-XXXX   XXXXX
F29:4    ###_XXX_###-XXXX   XXXXX
F29:5    ###_XXX_###-XXXX   XXXXX
F29:6    ###_XXX_###-XXXX   XXXXX
F29:7    ###_XXX_###-XXXX   XXXXX
F29:8    ###_XXX_###-XXXX   XXXXX
F29:9    ###_XXX_###-XXXX   XXXXX
F29:10   ###_XXX_###-XXXX   XXXXX
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you were close, but need TWO extra columns rather than just 1... One for the first part of the register, one for the second.

Assuming your data starts in cell `A2` (first column is headings), you'd have:

```
D2:  =LEFT(A2,FIND(":",A2)-1)
E2:  =MID(A2,FIND(":",A2)+1,1000)
```

Drag those formulas down and then sort your data first by column D, then by column E (and choose to sort anything that looks like a number as a number).

Hope that does the trick!!

Comment: Thank you John, An alteration of this did. I had some secondary registers which contained "N27:0/123" so I had to do a secondary replace statement to replace the forward slash with a decimal. But this worked! I appreciate it!